# How to write @Parameters method which uses parameter list from another class?

Tags: java, junit, parameterized

I am trying to run some parameterized test in Junit. My test has only one parameter so I can do something like that :

```
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
return Arrays.asList( new Object [][] {
            {new TestCase("AD", "sikuli", l)}});
}
```

In this way I can run the same test with different `TestCase` objects.The problem is that I want to receive an `ArrayList` of `TestCase` from another class, I don't want to create the TestCase objects here. Is there any way I could do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example below, substitute `getTestCaseList()` with a call to your other class that returns the `TestCase` objects:

```
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
  Collection<Object[]> result = new ArrayList<>();

  for (TestCase testCase : getTestCaseList()) {
    result.add(new Object[] {testCase});
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an interface with the set of test cases you want:

```
public interface MyTestCases {

    public Collection<Object[]> TESTCASE_SET_1 = Arrays.asList(
                   new Object[][] {{new TestCase("AD", "sikuli", l)}}); 

    // maybe followed by other sets of test cases
}
```

Here you can just return the collection defined in the interface.

```
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
    return MyTestCases.TESTCASE_SET_1;
}
```

Hope that helps.